# verifying which of my files were pushed

Tags: git, version-control, github

I'm using git on my Mac machine. And trying `SourceTree` (is it free?)

I have committed and pushed files from local branch `a` to remote `origin\a`.

A colleague merged from `origin\a` to `origin\b` and I have pulled a local `b`.

I don't see my changes in local `b`.

1) How can I see all the files I have pushed to `origin\a` in the last week? (ui-tool? and cmd?)

2) how can I explore remote branches without pulling them? (ui-tool? and cmd?)

3) How can I pull from `origin\b` to local `a`, even though they are not configured as one being trackable of the other?

4) Any recommendation for freeware git ui-tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, I'd suggest reading through [Pro Git, by Scott Chacon](http://git-scm.com/book) to get an understanding of how to use Git, since you seem to be having some trouble with some of Git's basic concepts.

Second, I'll answer each of your questions in turn using git terminal commands. You will need your terminal to be at the root of your local repository for any of these to work:

1. You can find out which remote commits have your name on them by doing

   git log origin/a --author="<your_username>"

   Here, `your_username` is whatever the output of `git config user.name` is.

   If you want to find out which files you edited in each commit, add `--name-only` to your log command.
2. The previous command does just that. Generally, any command that takes a branch as an argument can take a remote branch as an argument as well, as long as you prefix the branch name with the remote name, in this case `origin`.
3. Use the command

   git pull origin b

   when you have your local `a` checked out to pull your changes from `origin/b` to local `a`.
4. Unfortunately I couldn't give you any recommendation for a graphical client since I never use one, but I will tell you why that's the case so you can decide for yourself if you need one.

   Git as a **massive** amount of functionality that makes it as powerful as it is, but any graphical client is only going to be able to expose a small fraction of that functionality through its interface if they don't want the user to spend their time looking at a solid wall of buttons and menus. That means if you ever want to use a feature that isn't exposed, you're going to have to drop into the terminal, but you're not going to know what you're doing there because you've spent most of your time in the client. I simply feel far more productive use Git from the terminal.

   That said, I briefly tried out [Gitx](http://gitx.org/) for the Mac and had no complaints about it's usability for day-to-day git tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommending using source tree as your gui tool
    http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/download/

source tree will display all the files + diff visually for you.

if you want command like simply type

```
gitk
```

in your bash window.